# Does the database tenet of using meaningless identifiers have name?

Tags: database-design

One of the basic tenets of database design is to use meaningless unrestricted identifiers. Does this rule/concept have an accepted name? Or do people just make something up on the fly like "the meaningless identifier rule" when referring to it in conversation?

Comment: Are you talking about [surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)?

Comment: Surrogate keys are invaluable but not a tenet. Natural or external identifiers and composite keys have their uses.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a basic tenet, and the way you put it doesn't even make practical sense. To be useful, most databases are required to be an accurate representation of some external reality. Users and consumers of data absolutely need identifiers that are meaningful and relevant outside the database. From a database design point of view those identifiers are known as business keys or natural keys.

The point of surrogate keys, if they are used at all, is that they are *in addition to*, not instead of, more "meaningful" identifiers. The obvious implication is that meaningful identifiers (meaningful in the external reality being represented) are far more important and fundamental in an information system than meaningless ones.

The basic criteria for identifiers are: uniqueness, minimality, simplicity, stability and familiarity.